# Unable to establish LAN session and establish IPMI v1.5 / RMCP session

Tags: arm, ipmitool

I have cross-compiled the latest ipmitool 1.8.18 from GitHub and ran the same on the armv5 Linux board.
I am able to run the command like help and show version, but if try to read any values from the sensor with a command like

`ipmitool -H 127.0.0.1 -U admin -P admin fru print`

then it gives a below error,

```
Error: Unable to establish LAN session
Error: Unable to establish IPMI v1.5 / RMCP session
```

However, I am able to run ipmitool 1.8.11 version command successfully.
Successful 1.8.11 command output:

```
/var/tmp # ./ipmitool_1.8.11 -H 127.0.0.1 -U admin -vvv chassis power status
Password:
ipmi_lan_send_cmd:opened=[0], open=[371780]
opened=[1], open=[371780]

IPMI Request Session Header (level 0)
Authtype : NONE
Sequence : 0x00000000
Session ID : 0xbabb631a
IPMI Request Message Header
Rs Addr : 20
NetFn : 00
Rs LUN : 0
Rq Addr : 81
Rq Seq : 01
Rq Lun : 0
Command : 01
send_packet (53 bytes)
1a 63 bb ba 04 35 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 24 1e 00 00
24 1e 00 00 00
recv_packet (4 bytes)
41 01 40 00
Chassis Power is on
/var/tmp #
```

Failed ipmitool 1.8.18 command output with verbose, tried with `-I lanplus` as well:

```
/var/tmp # ipmitool -H 127.0.0.1 -U admin -vvv chassis power status
Password:
Sending IPMI/RMCP presence ping packet
send_packet (12 bytes)
06 00 ff 06 00 00 11 be 80 00 00 00
ipmi_lan_send_cmd:opened=[1], open=[453156]

IPMI Request Session Header (level 0)
Authtype : NONE
Sequence : 0x00000000
Session ID : 0x00000000
IPMI Request Message Header
Rs Addr : 20
NetFn : 06
Rs LUN : 0
Rq Addr : 81
Rq Seq : 01
Rq Lun : 0
Command : 38
send_packet (23 bytes)
06 00 ff 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 20 18
c8 81 04 38 0e 04 31
IPMI Request Session Header (level 0)
Authtype : NONE
Sequence : 0x00000000
Session ID : 0x00000000
IPMI Request Message Header
Rs Addr : 20
NetFn : 06
Rs LUN : 0
Rq Addr : 81
Rq Seq : 01
Rq Lun : 0
Command : 38
send_packet (23 bytes)
06 00 ff 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 20 18
c8 81 04 38 0e 04 31
No response from remote controller
Get Auth Capabilities command failed
ipmi_lan_send_cmd:opened=[1], open=[453156]
IPMI Request Session Header (level 0)
Authtype : NONE
Sequence : 0x00000000
Session ID : 0x00000000
IPMI Request Message Header
Rs Addr : 20
NetFn : 06
Rs LUN : 0
Rq Addr : 81
Rq Seq : 02
Rq Lun : 0
Command : 38
send_packet (23 bytes)
06 00 ff 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 20 18
c8 81 08 38 0e 04 2d
IPMI Request Session Header (level 0)
Authtype : NONE
Sequence : 0x00000000
Session ID : 0x00000000
IPMI Request Message Header
Rs Addr : 20
NetFn : 06
Rs LUN : 0
Rq Addr : 81
Rq Seq : 02
Rq Lun : 0
Command : 38
send_packet (23 bytes)
06 00 ff 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 20 18
c8 81 08 38 0e 04 2d
No response from remote controller
Get Auth Capabilities command failed
Error: Unable to establish LAN session
Error: Unable to establish IPMI v1.5 / RMCP session
/var/tmp #
```

Could someone please help with this?

Thanks